# ExtJS Modal Panel is not displaying content

Tags: extjs

I have a modal panel which will appear when a link is clicked with a listener config.
The link is placed inside a grid. The problem is when the link is clicked the modal is appearing with no data. Please help.

```
listeners : {
                click : function() {
                    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        storeId:'myStore',
                        fields:['qname'],
                        data:{'items':[
                            { 'qname': 'Lisa'},
                            { 'qname': 'Bart'},
                            { 'qname': 'Homer'},
                            { 'qname': 'Marge'}
                        ]},
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'memory',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'items'
                            }
                        }
                    });

                        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                            title : 'Add Survey',
                            titleAlign : 'center',
                            id : 'surveyWindow',
                            height : 400,
                            width : 300,                                            
                            //modal : true,
                            layout : 'fit',
                            closeAction:'close',
                            store:Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore'),
                            items : {
                                xtype : 'grid',
                                id :'addSurveyGrid',
                                border : false,
                                columns : [{
                                    xtype : 'rownumberer'
                                },{
                                    header : 'Survey Name',
                                    sortable : false,
                                    dataIndex : 'qname',
                                    flex : 1
                                }]
                            }
                        }).show();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `store` to the `Window`, not the `grid`. [Fixed that for you](http://jsfiddle.net/themel/k3gGU/).

Comment: Thanks it resolved my issue !! That is a silly mistake I have committed.